# How to resize an extra box with disclosure triangle in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, window, resize, disclosure

How to resize an extra box with disclosure triangle in Cocoa?

```
- (IBAction)disclosureTriangleClicked:(id)sender {
    NSWindow *window =[sender window];
    NSRect frame = [window frame];
    [otherBox frame].size.height +14;
    switch([sender state]) {
        case NSOnState:
            [otherBox setHidden:NO];
            //Must resize!
            break;
        case NSOffState:
            [otherBox setHidden:YES];
            //Must resize!
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)disclosureTriangleClicked:(id)sender {
    NSWindow *window =[sender window];
    NSRect frameWinOld = [window frame];
    CGFloat heightWinOld = frameWinOld.size.height;
    NSRect frameOtherBox = [otherBox frame];
    CGFloat heightOtherBoxWithMargin = frameOtherBox.size.height +14;
    switch([sender state]) {
        case NSOnState:
            [window setFrame:NSRectMake(frameWinOld.origin.x, frameWinOld.origin.y, frameWinOld.width, frameWinOld.height + heightOtherBoxWithMargin) display:YES];
            [otherBox setHidden:NO];
            break;
        case NSOffState:
            [window setFrame:NSRectMake(frameWinOld.origin.x, frameWinOld.origin.y, frameWinOld.width, frameWinOld.height - heightOtherBoxWithMargin) display:YES];
            [otherBox setHidden:YES];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You mean the box stays exactly the same size? (Resizing is all you asked how to do.) Or is the problem that the box and/or other controls end up in the wrong position? If so, you need to adjust origin Ys as well, and/or set top/bottom struts in IB.

Comment: Sorry, my question isn't very clear which is why you might have misunderstood. I actually got it working. But I wanted to resize the window as the disclosure triangle is clicked, so that the "extra box" could appear in the extra window space.

Comment: Well, my comment wasn't very clear either. It actually IS the window that is being resized in the code, not the box. (Which makes sense.) So everything works OK now?